# Fading out animation on website startup

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a div that holds a .gif and shows up everytime the page starts (I'll store a value in user's session, so it doesn't show more than once after log in), then fades out. I have created a div, but it somehow doesn't show up if there's nothing inside, even when I type in height: 100%; width: 100%;.
Here's my code so far:

```
<style>
.fade {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 1111;
}
</style>

<div class="fade"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.fade {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 1111;
}
```

Always add fixed position if you want to cover all screen, especially if you don't disable scrolling while this div is shown.

Forgot about top and left. That's also very important!

Also, sometimes parent-child element relations can mess up your width/height if you use %. In that case:

```
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
```

That means browser's viewport height and width.

Comment: also add top:0px and left:0px

Comment: I forgot a thing and updated my answer, like user3091574 said - also set top and left (or right) to 0px.

Comment: Nothing. I can't see the div without typing in something, and even then, it's small and without the background.

Comment: 1) Make sure class name is same in HTML and CSS 2) Make sure BOTH are classes not that one of them is ID 3) Try width: 100vw; and height: 100vh;

Comment: Nevermind, the animation keyframes (marquee) were messing everything up because one tag was open. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Cheers! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Div `.fade` are in the `body`, which is in the `html`. And as we all know 100% of zero are still zero. Set height of those two equal 100% too:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Added it, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
.fade{
   min-width:100%;
   min-height:100%;
   background-color: #000;
   z-index: 1111;
   position:fixed;
}
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/7hm2aqn6/)

Comment: It works on JSFiddle, but doesn't work on my website. Why is that?

Comment: @Lnvz strange, what you see on your website? any screen? try z-index: 999999;